# python 3.5 Scipy package installation on windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, python-3.5

In windows 10 as an administrator in command prompt I want to install "scipy". But after this command : pip install sctipy I have been faced with these errors :

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
                                                                                Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-e1t3tsx1\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_67ezs94pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\administrator\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\administrator\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\administrator\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\administrator\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE


  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
```

How Can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend installing via a wheel if possible - it avoids need for compilation which, on Windows, can be a major pain. You may need to download further packages that scipy depends on. There's a great archive of wheel files here, courtesy of Christoph Gohlke: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

If you download a wheel, you can install by using pip as you normally would but referencing the wheel filename:

```
pip install SomePackage-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Personal tip - keep hold of the wheel files you need. Ones hosted on pypi are normally safe, but elsewhere they may disappear and/or be replaced by newer versions. Check for newer versions by all means, but you can be left in an awkward position if they disappear altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you reinstall your python setup tools it will solve the error :

```
pip uninstall setuptools
pip install setuptools
```